# MVC Ajax call to Controller Method with Parameter connects but Parameter value is null

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am able to connect my ajax call to the controller, but the parameter is showing as null when it reaches the controller. What is the correct way for me to pass parameters with this call?
'''

```
  //In the Index Controller
  [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult TestFunction(string par1)
    {
        int i = 2;
        return view()
    } 

    function onDropDownChange() {
    alert('We are starting to call function');

    var url = '/Index/TestFunction/Cat'
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {},
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) { alert('Successful call') },
        error: function () {alert('Failed Call')}
        })
}  

   '''
```

Comment: Please pass `data` into ajax parameter

Comment: `data: {}` just for checking `data: {par1:"Test value"},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data` option of ajax. You can send data object to server by data option in ajax.

Example--

```
 function onDropDownChange() {

    var url = '/Index/TestFunction/Cat'
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {par1: "Some value"},//pass your obect
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) { alert('Successful call') },
        error: function () {alert('Failed Call')}
        })
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I didnt realize that you needed to have the parameter slot tacked onto the end of the url AND in the data part.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this bind drop-down value in controller action

```
function onDropDownChange(elem) {
    alert('We are starting to call function');

    var url = '/Index/TestFunction/Cat'
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {par1:$(elem).val()},
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) { alert('Successful call') },
        error: function () {alert('Failed Call')}
        })
}
```

In view need to pass this argument while calling this function.

Like eg

```
<select onchange="onDropDownChange(this)">
///<option> tag
</select>
```